# How do I reduce the size of a specific SVG in a flex box?

Tags: html, css, svg, mobile-website, static-site

I have a static website at [www.poggen.com](http://www.poggen.com), I am trying to reduce the size of the logo in the third flex box from the right to match the other two, but I am not able to make any changes at all. I tried adding the height and width attributes to the SVG directly (`<svg style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;"`) but that did not make any difference other than making the SVG near indecipherable on the mobile site. How do I make the SVG smaller to match the other two logos and a normal size on mobile? Please help [image: Third flex box with a SVG logo]

**Edit -** Changing the `.text-image img` width changes the size of all three SVG logos.

Here's my CSS for the infoflex boxes and the corresponding image-container. I am not sure why the mobile SVG has reduced in size significantly but the widescreen site remains the same.

```
/*infoboxemain css*/
.infoboxemain {
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.infoboxemain .infoflexbox {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: -105px -30px 0;
}

.infoboxemain .infoboxes {
    background: #EFF3F9;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 30px;
    width: calc(33.33% - 60px);
    padding: 0px;
}


.infoboxemain .infoboxes .image-container .bg-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.infoboxemain .infoboxes .image-container .text-image {
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.text-image img {
    width: 95%;
}

.infoboxemain .infoboxes .image-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: You may need to set a viewBox attribute and remove the width and height of the svg element. Also poggen.com is not accesible.

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question. Remove the image and create a ["Stack Snippets"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).